# filter: drop shadow just on background

Tags: css, dropshadow

I am using a .png image and **I want to create a big white shadow**, like an aura, around it; but **I want it just to affect the background**, and not text and other elements I have in the page!

How it could be helped? Is there a method for making the shadow hit just the background? **Or i can't at all?** Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
    <div id="round"></div>
    <div class="text">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#round {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 40px red);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.background {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.text {
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

This way the shadow will be reflected on the text, that is not what i want to archieve.

As asked, also a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/k371t6jd/

Comment: Post some code, please.

Comment: can you please provide your code.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I added the code and a fiddle...

Comment: I really think we need an image of what this is **supposed** to look like.

Comment: like it is shown in the fiddle, it is like an aura; i changed the colors to exaggerate the problem.

Comment: The fiddle shows me nothing...that's why the design image woudl be preferable.

Comment: It shows that the glow of the shadow overlap the text, making it different in color while i don't want the glow to affect the text or the other white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody could give an answer. The solution was: you can't. Regards.